# iOS is ignoring ajax requests (Cordova)

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova

I've been building web based app, with cordova and Xcode, and it seems that the Xcode / simulator is ignoring my ajax requests. I know the issue with ATS and therefore added the extra code to the plist :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>orlanoar.com/*</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
          <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
      </dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Also added the plugins : cordova-plugin-transport-security and cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. When I mean ignores, is that I don't get the ssl error or ats error that other people get in the console.

please help me, thanks.

Comment: I m not sure why u wanna manipulate plist file when u add the transport security plugin as it does the same

Comment: Do some debugging first. Go to your `config.xml` and add this: `<access origin="*" />`. Does it work with this.

Comment: Also check the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...>` element in your `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest version of Cordova.

And it is necessary to have [WhiteList](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ_4nrgIrPAhUMJ5oKHW59DUcQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcordova.apache.org%2Fdocs%2Fen%2Flatest%2Freference%2Fcordova-plugin-whitelist%2F&usg=AFQjCNErlUDDAn6dou8lV2FytuRGvnWiqg&sig2=2T7QSB9GB19hxKdGEjbPkA) plugin for network requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it: I didn't have `http` before the URL.

Thanks!